# Почему ASLR не выключается для значений из кучи?

Tags: c++, c, структуры-данных

Скажем, я хочу отладить структуру данных и для простоты хочу иметь одинаковые адреса в памяти. Очевидно, что для этого нужно отключить ASLR. Потому поступаю как [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561294/8313610).

Процесс запускается от администратора. В ProcessHacker в этом процессе вижу, что ASLR выключен.

Вот пример программы:

```
#include<iostream>


struct Node {
     int Data;
     Node* next;
};

Node* add(Node* head, int Value)
{
     Node* New = new Node;
     New->Data = Value;
     New->next = head;
     return New;
}

void Show(Node* head)
{
     while (head)
     {
          printf("%p \n", head);
          head = head->next;
     }
     printf("Adress of show func %p\n", &Show);
     while (1);
     
}


int main()
{
     Node* a = nullptr;

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          a = add(a, i);

     Show(a);

}
```

Первый запуск программы:

```
005AED48
005A5538
005A5500
005A5680
005A5648
Adress of show func 00411447
```

Второй запуск:

```
006E5538
006E5500
006E5680
006E5648
006E05A0
Adress of show func 00411447
```

Почему адреса значений из кучи всё ещё рандомизируются? Я хочу, чтобы они повторялись от запуска к запуску

Comment: Применительно к исполняемым файлам ASLR (/DYNAMICBASE) влияет на адрес загруженного образа.

Comment: @user7860670, ну да, например, dll'ка будет всегда загружаться по определеному адресу. Но раз исполняемый файл отобржается в память в каждый раз разное место, то и адреса функций будут разными. А на кучу это влияет?

Comment: На кучу и на стек это никак не влияет, они же не привязаны к исполняемым файлам. Кроме того, даже если бы один базовый адрес кучи был фиксирован, то это в любом случае не было бы гарантией того, что выделяемые в ней блоки памяти каждый раз имели бы одинаковые адреса.

Answer (score 2):

Говорят, что на линуксе помогает `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20003589/2752075)

Answer (score 0):

Действителльно, @user7860670 прав. Куча всегда рандомизирована и отключение ASLR повлиять на это не может. [В этом ответе](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?875441-RESOLVED-ASLR-amp-Heap-Address&p=5393225&viewfull=1#post5393225) сказано:

> Heaps and some other strucutres are randomized always.